# MessageBox.Show(TimeSpan)

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox, timespan

i would like to show a `TimeSpan` in a `MessageBox` but am getting an error:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(byear, bmonth, bday, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime datenow =  DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan age = datenow - date1;
MessageBox.Show(ToString(age));
```

`Error  1   No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments`

how do i output a messagebox with `TimeSpan`?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(age.ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or you can do `Convert.ToString(age)` to keep with the format that you have now.

Answer (score 11):

```
MessageBox.Show(age.ToString());
```

Though you might not like the result.  If you want a specific format you have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

That's not going to look great, TimeSpan is missing a decent ToString() override on .NET 3.5 and earlier.  Work around that by using the DateTime.ToString() method:

```
  string txt = new DateTime(Math.Abs(age.Ticks)).ToString("h:mm:ss");
  if (age.Ticks < 0) txt = "-" + txt;
  MessageBox.Show(txt);
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to do `age.ToString()`